# Redirect an URL including deep links

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, cpanel

I have a domain that I would like to redirect to another domain including its deep links.

For example:
Domain-1.com/example should redirect to Domain-2.com/example.

How do I set this up, and is it possible to do in cPanel?

PS - I have no programming experience, so please explain to me how I can implement this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?Domain-1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://Domain-2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite In-Depth Details](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)